# Fluent Async validation with multiple parameters

Tags: c#, .net, fluentvalidation

```
public class BookValidator : AbstractValidator<Book>
{
   private readonly IRepository _repository;
   public BookValidator(IRepository repository)
   {
       _repository = repository;

       // 
       RuleFor(m=> new {m.Code, m.InternalCode})
              .MustAsync(c=> BookExists(new {c.Code, c.InternalCode }))
              .WithMessage("Book exists");
   }

   private async Task<BookExists>(object arg1, CancellationToken token)
   {
      //return _repository.BookExists(code, internalCode);
   }
}
```

> Delegate Func<< Anonymous type: string code, string internalCode,
> CancellationToken, Task does not take 1 argument>>

Answer (score 0):

Too little information (for someone with 13k rep, come on...), but I think you are missing `CancellationToken` argument in your lambda:

```cs
//...
.MustAsync((c, cancel) => this.BookExists(new {c.Code, c.InternalCode }, cancel))
//...
```